# How to prevent Azure CLI's `swa deploy` from creating a .ZIP folder?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app, swa-cli

Every time I deploy an Azure static web app using `swa deploy`, it creates an unnecessary `.zip` folder at the root of my application:

[image]

Found no option in the docs to disabled this, so for now I have to delete these folders manually every time I make a deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this prevents the zip files from being created, but I did add `*.\\*` to my .gitignore so that at least these aren't seen by git. Might also be worth adding a post build command to remove these on deploy.